# What is the operator **?

Tags: vector, operators

In mathematica if you run:

```
In[83]:= M = Table[Subscript[m, i], {i, 3}] ;
P = Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 3}];
Q = Table[Subscript[q, i], {i, 3}];
fn[t1_, t2_] := #.# &[t1 P - t2 Q + M];
fnSym = fn[t1, t2]

Out[87]= (Subscript[m, 1] + t1 Subscript[p, 1] - 
    t2 Subscript[q, 1]) ** (Subscript[m, 1] + t1 Subscript[p, 1] - 
    t2 Subscript[q, 1]) + (Subscript[m, 2] + t1 Subscript[p, 2] - 
    t2 Subscript[q, 2]) ** (Subscript[m, 2] + t1 Subscript[p, 2] - 
    t2 Subscript[q, 2]) + (Subscript[m, 3] + t1 Subscript[p, 3] - 
    t2 Subscript[q, 3]) ** (Subscript[m, 3] + t1 Subscript[p, 3] - 
    t2 Subscript[q, 3])
```

The result contains lots of double asterisk **, which I cannot find anywhere in their operator list (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Operators.html)

So what does it mean?

Comment: If you type ** into the search field of the Documentation Center, you will find that it is the operator form of `NonCommutativeMultiply`

Comment: `**` won't appear in the result unless it also appeared in your input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this was missing from [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121#25616) I'll answer.  `**` is shorthand for [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) as can be seen with [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html):

```
FullForm[a ** b ** c] // HoldForm
```

> ```
> NonCommutativeMultiply[a, b, c]
> ```

Or highlight `**` in the Front End and press <kbd>F1</kbd>, which should open a *Search Results* Notebook with a single entry for

> NonCommutativeMultiply (Built-in Wolfram Language Symbol)
>   a ** b ** c is a general associative, but non-commutative, form of multiplication.

Comment: An addition for everybody else reading: as can be ascertained from the name of the operator, it's a useful operation if you want to define non-commutative multiplication for objects you have (e.g. in the quaternion package).